# How do I earn the Tornado Valley achievement in Tropico 4?

Tags: achievements, tropico-4

What is the easiest way to unlock the achievement Tornado Valley (Survive a tornado outbreak with no human causalities)? I always seem to have multiple buildings destroyed along with numerous citizen deaths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrading the weather station will warn your citizens and get them to shelter.

Comment: Confirmed. I was able to get the "Head for High Ground" achievement by adding the tsunami detection upgrade as well.